# Is it possible to programmatically select an option in a controlled segment by the name rather than the index?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make the segment selected by the name that it is labeled by rather than index with `setSelectedSegmentIndex:0` also I dont want to go through and define each index with the labeled name manually. How can I do this?

Comment: Not to be too sarcastic, but I'd like lots of things too. Writing this kind of adaption method as either a category or just a utility method on some class is a very common thing to do in both OSX and iOS. It cannot take more than 5 minutes to write.

Comment: @DavidH And how would I do this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just created a category for that, you'll be able to find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Altimor/UISegmentedControl-SelectSegmentCalled).

Simply import the category in the file you want to use it in, and then:

```
[yourControl selectSegmentCalled:@"The Name"];
```

Comment: That was quick! Thanks, saved me the effort - +1 :-)

Comment: No need for the `break` in the code - return will exit the method. Also maybe call it `selectCellNamed` per apple convention?

Comment: Thank you for the github example this was really helpful since I have not used categories before. Very helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's not worth it - use index:

```
NSString* title = @"My Title";

for (int i = 0; i < control.numberOfSegments; i ++)
{
   if ([[control titleForSegmentAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:title])
   {
        control.selectedSegmentIndex = i;
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Agreed - this is the right way to do the feature - but as a snippet it has to get copy and pasted everywhere its needed. IMHO these often make nice utilities to add to a class: +(NSUInteger)segment:(UISegmentedControl *)cntl withName:(NSString *)name - I prefer that over categories but it's more or less the same either way.

Comment: @DavidH agreed - if you were actually going to use this then do it in a category.